# Check if an user has given as an input 1 or more then 1 in an batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file, ms-dos

I am having an question with an Batch file
Is it possible to let an user choose how many files it will enter?

For example

```
set /p count=Enter the number of files you are willing to set: 
IF %count% == 1 GOTO 1
IF %count% > 1 GOTO MORE
:1
rest of the code
:MORE
rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could build a loop like this:

```
@echo off
set /p count="Enter the number of files: " 
echo Your selection: %count%
set f=1
:start
set /p file="Enter file number %f%: " 
echo File: %file%
set /a f+=1
if %f% LEQ %count% goto start
```

After receiving the file count the script asks the user a new input **count** times. The **f** control variable is incremented on every new input until it reaches **count** and the final condition changes. Thus it doesn't jump to **start** and script ends.